# Can I stop Outlook audio notifications for non-focused messages only?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I like Office 365/Outlook's new 'focused' inbox - it seems to do a great job of sorting the wheat from the chaff. I also like to get an audio alert when new mail arrives. But I've found that the audio alert is triggered for both 'focused' and 'other' messages alike, since they both are part of the 'inbox' folder.

Is there a way to only get an audio alert for 'focused' messages?

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround of sorts. You can turn off email alerts (under File>Options>Mail) and then create a rule (under File>Manage Rules & Alerts>New Rule) to play a notification when certain criteria are met. For example, all emails with your email address in the TO or CC box. Unfortunately, "delivered to Focused inbox" is not currently a criteria you can select.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no built-in option available to turn on new mail alert for "Focused" messages only. You may submit your feedback via the Outlook user interface or to the [Outlook UserVoice forum](https://outlook.uservoice.com/) so that the product team can hear your suggestion.